# Call One Method Before Another Angular

Tags: angular, methods, observable

I do have the following 2 methods:

```
private rowClicked : any;

  onButtonClicked() {
    console.log(this.rowClicked) // undefined
  }
  onRowClicked(event: any)() { 
     this.rowClicked = event.data;
  }
```

I do want to delete a row in my ag-grid when clicking a button present on every row. However, when clicking on the button without being clicked on the row itself first, the selected Row cannot be stored ( is undefined ).

I figured out that inside onRowClicked method i have access to my selected row even tho i click first only on the button( without row being selected).

So, what I was thinking is to get my row inside the *onRowClicked()* and then pass it to *onButtonClicked()*.

By default and due to application constraints, **onButtonClicked()** is called *BEFORE* **onRowClicked()**, which causes *this.property* within *onButtonClicked()* to be undefined.

How can I impose *onRowClicked()* to be called before *onButtonClicked()*?

Comment: Call `methodOne` inside `methodTwo`?

Comment: cant, methodOne has an event as parameter which can not be provided inside methodTwo ..

Comment: What triggers that event? Some more context might help.

Comment: i tried to edit a bit my question with additional details

Comment: can you share the html as well

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using the button as a part of your grid, then you can take advantage of cellclicked event and get rid of buttonClicked and rowClciked event. Cellclick should be able to handle your request!
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag in the button click event, and process the command if the flag is set when the row click event is triggered:

```
private rowClicked : any;
private shouldProcessCommand = false;

onButtonClicked() {
  this.shouldProcessCommand= true;
}

onRowClicked(event) {
  this.rowClicked = event.data;

  if (this.shouldProcessCommand) {
    this.shouldProcessCommand= false;

    // Do some processing with rowClicked
    ...
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjx72x) for a demo.